# Twitter Bootstrap - Appending numeric stepper inline next to an input field

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to code this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/233981/Numerical_slider.PNG

After some research, I found http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/ which seemed like a great start.

So far I have:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Label 1</label>
  <div class="controls">    
  <input type="text" data-slider="true" value="0.6" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-theme="volume">  
  </div>
 </div>
```

This works fine for the slider, but now I'm trying to put a numeric stepper next to the slider. Hence:

```
<input type="number" class="input-mini" value="60">
```

I've been fiddling with `input-append` and `help-inline` trying to get the numeric stepper to sit nicely next to the slider but it just isn't flying. I keep getting some variation of the `<input type="number">` field showing below the slider rather than next to.

How can I move the number input field to the right hand side of the slider?

Comment: If I fiddle what you gave us it works fine. Is the div with class controls wide enough to accommodate your inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following CSS (`slidernumber` is a class assigned to the input field):

```
.slidernumber
{
    float: left;
}
.slider-volume {
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

The two widgets then are side by side using this HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Label 1</label>
  <div class="controls smallgroup">    
      <input type="text" data-slider="true" value="0.6" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-theme="volume"/>  
      <input type="number" class="input-mini slidernumber" value="60"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zydxG/1/).